# Is it possible to conclude surjective from this theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have this following theorem in my book :

Let $V,W$ be linear spaces over field $F$, let $$B=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$$  is a base of linear space $V$ and let $\{w_1,....w_n\}$ are vectors in linear space $W$ then only one linear transformation from $T:V \rightarrow W$ exists that implies

$$i=1,..,n$$
$$T(v_i)=w_i$$

I can understand the function isn't injective for example in case $w_1=w_2$ but I'm not sure about surjectivity.

My question is in case the terms of this theorem apply, could I conclude that for all $w \in W$ there exists $v \in V$ so $T(v)=w$

Meaning that the function is surjective? or else could I conclude that for all $w \in ImT$ exist $v \in V$ so $T(v)=w$?

I got confused with the wording of the theorem, I'll be very glad if someone can clear this matter.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: it has nothing to do with subjectivity. The theorem says that a linear map is uniquely defined by its values on a basis. Notice $w_1, \dotsc , w_n$ need not be a basis of $W$.

Comment: @user251257 I undestand that $\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ doesn't have to be basis for linear space $W$, however the theorem says that let $\{w_1,..,w_n\}$ meaning that I can choose whatever $\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ I want in linear space $W$ and If I could choose any $\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ I want it means that it surjective.

Comment: if $w_1, \dotsc, w_n$ span $W$, then $T$ is subjective. In general $T$ need not be subjective.

Comment: @JaVaPG Note that the function $T$ depends on the vectors $w_i$. So for some choices of the $w_i$, the resulting map will be surjective; for others (say, for example, $w_i = 0$ for all $i$) it will not.

Comment: @user251257 Do you have any example for a transformation that is not surjective? that applies the terms of theorem written in the question?

Comment: @JaVaPG take $w_1 = \dotsb = w_n = 0$. Then, $T=0$ and is not surjective, if $W\ne \{0\}$.

Comment: @user251257 I understand the the function doesn't have to be surjective, but I can say from this theorem that for any $w \in ImT$ exist $v \in V$ that implies $T(v)=w$ right?

Comment: @JaVaPG that is the definition of image of $T$

Comment: @user251257 Thank you both for your help :) one last question if I may, I know that for any $w \in ImT$ exist $v \in V$ that implies $T(v)=w$ from the definition even without the theorem above right? it appiles for any linear transformation.

Comment: @JaVaPG it applies to any function. it is the very definition of image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear function will be surjective when considered as a function $f:V\to\text{span}(w_1,\dots,w_n)\subset W$